# Type Error, Need a Y/N user confirmation. Python

Tags: python, types, typeerror

I am working on a function that will delete records of individuals but before doing so, it will display:

```
Are you sure you want to delete record with Last Name: Apple, First Name: Amy ? Enter Y or N
```

I got through most of my function. I am having difficulty with this Yes or No part. The code I have for the delete function so far is as follows

```
def delete_student():
    global student_info
    global database

    print("--- Delete Student ---")
    roll = input("Enter a Last Name: ")
    student_found = False
    updated_data = []
    with open(database, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        counter = 0
        for row in reader:
            if len(row) > 0:
                if roll != row[2]:
                    updated_data.append(row)
                    counter += 1
                else:
                    student_found = True

    if student_found is True:

        if input("Are you sure you want to delete record", roll,  "(y/n) ") != "y":
            exit()
        with open(database, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerows(updated_data)
        print("Student ", roll, "deleted successfully")
    else:
        print("Record not found")

    input("Press any key to continue")
```

This gives me a Type Error, I need to display the name of the person as confirmation before deleting the record. Y/N input.

Type Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jake./PycharmProjects/Munyak_Jacob_FinalProject/FileRecords.py", line 58, in <module>
    delete_student()
  File "/Users/jake./PycharmProjects/Munyak_Jacob_FinalProject/deleteRecord.py", line 27, in delete_student
    if input("Are you sure you want to delete record", roll,  "(y/n) ") != "y":
TypeError: input expected at most 1 argument, got 3

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`input` takes a single string as a parameter, but you've provided three.  Construct a single string:

```
if input(f"Are you sure you want to delete record {roll} (y/n)? ") != "y":
```